# How to replace a running function in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Suppose we use SBCL's #'save-lisp-and-die to create an server applicatioon App1, which works very well.  Now we want to replace a function #'func1 with a new version without stopping App1.   How can we do it in Common Lisp ?

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: Please clarify: do you refer to replacing a function in a running lisp program OR do you refere to replacing function while it is being called (e.g., in some long loop)?

Comment: I mean replacing a function, which may be running or not,  in a running lisp program .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the new function definition. Then new function will be available immediately; code will call newly loaded function.

New function definition may be loaded in many ways:

- `(load (compile-file "file.lisp"))` where `file.lisp` is a source code for function
- `(load "file.fasl")` where `file.fasl` is compiled source code
- `(eval (defun ...))`

Of course, there are exceptions and complications:

- This will not replace already running calls of previous functions; for example, an infinite event loop can not be changed this way - it will have to support some kind of stopping and calling a new function. However, such long-running functions are rare. It can be worked around by using recursion instead of looping (but not all compilers do tail-call optimization).
- If you somewhere grabbed a pointer to function (for example, by `(function FOO)` where `FOO` is the name of a function), it will retain its old value. To avoid this, use symbols instead of function pointers (symbols are `funcall`able).
- The code of a function is a subject to garbage collection. You should be careful not to leave references to old versions of a function lying around. Also, if some functions become not needed, you should not forget to `fmakunbound` their symbols.
- If the function was used at compile time, all of the affected code should also be reloaded
- If you had high levels of optimization (which is not by default), compiler might have inlined the function into others. CLHS discriminates the cases when redefining a function becomes «undefined behavior».

But in practice, code reloading works well in most Common Lisp implementations.

Answer (score 10):

I personally ensure that SWANK (the server part of SLIME) is running, so that I can connect to the image at any time with Emacs+SLIME and redefine whatever I want.

```
(ql:quickload "swank")
(swank:start-server :port 1234) ;; listen for SLIME connections on port 1234
```

Then in Emacs, you can `M-x slime-connect`, and follow the prompts.

If you don’t want to do this for whatever reason, your implementation might offer something specific.

Comment: Do you mean we should include swank in the released image ?

Comment: You could also watch a directory for new patch files that then would be `load`ed replacing functionality while the program is running.

Comment: I don’t see a problem with putting swank in the released image, if you really want to be able to hot-patch it at production-time. Just make sure the port is secure somehow.

Comment: However, i am used to use VIM. Can  i use VIM to connect swank ?

Comment: @z_axis: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2531 seems to be the ticket

Comment: But how do you have something running in your image with swank along with having ability to redefine whatever you want? Swank gives me only repl buffer in emacs. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PF4Public: Exactly as I have described. You can run your favourite Lisp independently of Emacs, starting a Swank server (as advised), and connect to it later if you wish from Emacs+SLIME (as advised). Using slime-connect will then connect you to that very Lisp process.

Comment: @Justin Megawarne: I could be easily misunderstanding something. When I call swank from lisp interpreter (be it clisp or sbcl) it blocks everything. At this point I can connect from emacs with slime, but all I get is repl buffer (as I wrote earlier), so that if I start an infinite loop printing "Hello World", I still cannot do anything with this image until I stop this function, neither I can redefine it to print something different on the fly. Has it something to do with multithreading? As I understand interpreters I use are not compiled with multithreading.

Comment: @PF4Public: Yes, it sounds like a multithreading problem. SBCL is fairly easy to recompile from scratch (if you have an existing working installation), so you might want to give that a shot. See the relevant section here: http://www.sbcl.org/getting.html. Otherwise, your distribution might have an installation flag. Good luck!

Comment: @Justin Megawarne: toying with emacs and sbcl I've done this: `(make-thread (lambda () (swank:start-server "dfghfgh")))`. So now I have an image with swank along with repl buffer. Also I can connect to it from emacs and redefine functions at both repl buffers (emacs and terminal). Now I wonder why don't you suggest putting swank to a separate thread? The only reasonable explanation I can guess is that you run **your software** in separate thread instead. Am I right?

Comment: @Justin Megawarne: I think I've got it. At first I tried to start swank in clisp and doing so immediately blocks input. By mistake I believed the same would happen in sbcl, but it was not. Sorry for bothering you. Anyway this could be usefull for someone. `*features*` of clisp does not indicate any threading, while sbcl at least gives sb-thread, which I think allows sbcl to run swank properly.

Comment: Also I'd like to notice that if you run swank, you should `swank:stop-server` and stop any other threads if any before `save-lisp-and-die`, since sbcl is unable to save image with threads.

Comment: I personally just used this answer to run swank and it's awesome.  My entry point was a "Hello world"/sleep function which ran an infinite TCO loop on itself. I was able to redefine everything while the program was running. Add functions, define new variables, redefine main itself. Blew my mind.